# Sync jquery request wait finish before try to get the next request

Tags: jquery

i have read many threads,questions for my Problem and i have find a answer.
But i want to aks if my function is ok.

I have to work off forms with differnet ids on an onclick event.

```
function setBoocking() {
    if ($('.ajaxre').length) {
        var key = 0;
        //var ajaxboocking = [];
        var sotredPDF = new Array();
        $('.ajaxre').each(function () {
            var form = $(this);
            var data = form.serialize();
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                timeout: 4000,
                url: "ajaxloader.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: data,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function ($data) {
                    if ($data != null) {
                        if ($data.status == 1) {
                            alert("all fine"):
                        }
                    }
                },
                error: function ($databack) {
                    ajaxfehler('normal');
                    loading('end');
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

html

```
<div class="ajaxre">
    <form class="ajaxre" id="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="test" value="test1" />
    </form>
</div>
<div class="ajaxre">
    <form class="ajaxre" id="2">
        <input type="hidden" name="test" value="test2" />
    </form>
</div>
<div class="ajaxre">
    <form class="ajaxre" id="3">
        <input type="hidden" name="test" value="test3" />
    </form>
</div>
<br />
<br /><a onclick="setBoocking();">test</a>
```

So you see i have in my ajax Request async:false. That works. But can i make my function use asynchronus requests "i will set timout function" dont work withs asnc, and wait that one reuest is done or get error and then try the next request?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The HTML PART: "<div class="ajaxre"><form class="ajaxre" id="1"><input type="hidden" name="test" value="test1" /></form></div>
<div class="ajaxre"><form class="ajaxre" id="2"><input type="hidden" name="test" value="test2" /></form></div>
<div class="ajaxre"><form class="ajaxre" id="3"><input type="hidden" name="test" value="test3" /></form></div><br /><br /><a onclick="setBoocking();">testen</a>"

Comment: You can edit your post

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, delay function invocation, by one second, if if request happen.

```
var pause = false;
function request(data) {
    if (!pause) {
        pause = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajaxloader.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function ($data) {
                if ($data != null) {
                    if ($data.status == 1) {
                        alert("all fine");
                        pause = false;
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function ($databack) {
                ajaxfehler('normal');
                loading('end');
                pause = false;
            }
        });
    } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            request(data);
        }, 1000);
    }
}


function setBoocking() {
    if ($('.ajaxre').length) {
        var key = 0;
        //var ajaxboocking = [];
        var sotredPDF = new Array();
        var in_request = false;
        $('.ajaxre').each(function () {
            request($(this).serialize());
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @jcubuc thanks. That works but that makes an endless loop. I want to get the form serialize for example only thie 3 fomrs "<div class="ajaxre"><form class="ajaxre" id="1"><input type="hidden" name="test" value="test1" /></form></div> <div class="ajaxre"><form class="ajaxre" id="2"><input type="hidden" name="test" value="test2" /></form></div> <div class="ajaxre"><form class="ajaxre" id="3"><input type="hidden" name="test" value="test3" /></form></div><br /><br /><a onclick="setBoocking();">testen</a>"

Comment: sorry my misstake. i have 6 times class"ajaxre" on my html code Thanks its work fine

Answer (score 0):

Ajax requests returned what's know as a deferred, what you could do is store the response of all the ajax requests in an array and then use.

```
$.when.apply($, promises).then(function(){
});
```

This will then allow all of your calls to run async. (Promises is an array of the ajax deferred objects).

This post should help you understand fully :

http://richardneililagan.com/2011/05/using-deferred-objects-in-jquery-1-5/